# Is it possible to extend the functionality of an iterator in Java?

Tags: java, iterator

I was wondering if there is a way to extend the functionality of the iterator interface. Suppose that we have a Class that implements the Iterable interface (in the example above, instead of the overridden functions of the Iterator interface I have added myFunction).

```
public class MyClass implements Iterable{

    @Override
    public Iterator iterator() {
        return new Iterator() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
            }

            @Override
            public Tuple next() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
            }
            public void myFunction(){

            }
        };
    }
}
```

If I put this code in another function I get compilation error ("cannot find symbol") and I was wondering why this happens.

```
public void anotherFunction(){
    MyClass a = new MyClass();
    a.iterator().myFunction();
}
```

Comment: What particular function are you trying to add?  What _is_ `myFunction()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, of course. You could create another interface:

```
interface MyBetterIterator extends Iterator
{
    void myFunction();
}
```

then make the method return your type:

```
public class MyClass implements Iterable{

    @Override
    public MyBetterIterator iterator() {
...
    }
}
```

The feature is called "return type covariance", introduced in Java 5.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you have added a function of your own to the `Iterator` instance, all you have told the classes that consume your class is that you are returning an `Iterator`.  This means you are limited to the signature that the `Iterator` interface exposes.  If you want access to the myFunction, you will have to formally declare your own interface that extends `Iterator` and then make your `iterator()` function return that instead.  However, this will also break the `Iterable` contract, so you have to make that choice.

Comment: It will not break the `Iterable` interface if the custom interface extends the `Iterator` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your `myFunction()` doesn't belong to the `Iterator` interface and therefore cannot be used on an Object declared with the type `Iterator`.

```
a.iterator().myFunction();
  ^
  Returns an Iterator and therefore gives a compilation error
```